# OFFSET on AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I would like to run a query on AWS Athena with both a `LIMIT` and an `OFFSET` clause. I take it the former is supported while [the latter is not](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2661). Is there any way of emulating this functionality using other methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `OFFSET` for pagination is very inefficient, especially for an analytic database like Presto that often has to perform a full table or partition scan. Additionally, the results will not necessarily be consistent between queries, so you can have duplicate or missing results when navigating between pages.

In an `OLTP` database like MySQL or PostgreSQL, it's better to use a range query over an index, where you keep track of the last value seen on the previous page.

In an `OLAP` database like Presto, it's better to cache the result set and perform pagination using the cached data. You don't want to run an expensive query over billions or trillions of rows each time the user clicks to go to a different page.

See these articles for a longer explanation of the problem and the index approach:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset
- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: Notice that OFFSET syntax is available in Trino since 311. See https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-311.html?highlight=offset#general