# AWS Athena (Presto) OFFSET support

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I would like to know if there is support for OFFSET in AWS Athena. For mysql the following query is running but in athena it is giving me error. Any example would be helpful.

select * from employee where empSal >3000 LIMIT 300 OFFSET 20

Comment: OFFSET is now supported in Athena. Please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2021-10-04.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Athena is basically managed Presto. Since [Presto 311](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-311.html) you can use `OFFSET m LIMIT n` syntax or ANSI SQL equivalent: `OFFSET m ROWS FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY`.

You can read more in [Beyond LIMIT, Presto meets OFFSET and TIES](https://prestosql.io/blog/2020/02/03/beyond-limit-presto-meets-offset-and-ties.html).

**For older versions (and this includes AWS Athena as of this writing)**, you  can use [`row_number()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number) window function to implement OFFSET + LIMIT.

For example, instead of

```
SELECT * FROM elb_logs
OFFSET 5 LIMIT 5 -- this doesn't work, obviously
```

You can execute

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT row_number() over() AS rn, * FROM elb_logs)
WHERE rn BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

Note: the execution engine will still need to read offset+limit rows from the underlying table, but this is still much better than sending all these rows back to the client and taking a sublist there.

Warning: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45114359/65458 for explanation why avoiding OFFSET in queries is generally a good idea.

Comment: This answer is not helpful for those using Athena because, as of writing this, Athena does not use a version of presto that supports the `OFFSET` keyword.

Comment: @xno that's why i am providing both: the current Presto syntax and  legacy syntax for Athena.

Answer (score 4):

OFFSET Is not supported by AWS Athena. You can see all the supported SELECT parameters here: [SELECT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html)

Comment: thanks for reply. but then how will I fetch the in between rows using SELECT. My requirement is to fetch first 10K rows based on a condition and then take 5001 to 10K rows.

Comment: The data scanned appears to be the same if you use or not the LIMIT parameter so I think you need to cache all the received rows and then use the cached data to take only the rows from 5001 to 10K.

Comment: OFFSET is now supported. Please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2021-10-04.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the current accepted solution does not work properly with the `ORDER BY` keyword as the `row_number()` is applied before ordering. I believe an exact solution allowing you to use `ORDER BY` would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT row_number() over() AS rn, *
  FROM ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM elb_logs
    ORDER BY id ASC 
  )
)
WHERE rn BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

OFFSET is supported by Athena engine version 2

```
[ WITH with_query [, ...] ]
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] select_expression [, ...]
[ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
[ WHERE condition ]
[ GROUP BY [ ALL | DISTINCT ] grouping_element [, ...] ]
[ HAVING condition ]
[ { UNION | INTERSECT | EXCEPT } [ ALL | DISTINCT ] select ]
[ ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ] [ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST] [, ...] ]
[ OFFSET count [ ROW | ROWS ] ]
[ LIMIT [ count | ALL ] ]
```

Link for documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could limit and filter by a natural key of the data.

For example, if you had an `id` column in your dataset you could do the following:

```
SELECT id, * FROM elb_logs
WHERE id > __LAST_SEEN_ID__
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 500
```

So your offset would be defined implicitly, using the filter, based on the last id that you have processed.