# How to use LIMIT OFFSET in AWS Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to replicate the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_name LIMIT 100, 10;
```

The same query doesn't work in Athena, and when I looked up the [Athena Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html), it seems like `LIMIT` only accepts one value i.e. the count. So, only queries like `LIMIT 100` would work.

So, how do we implement pagination for tables in Athena?

Comment: There are better ways than offset for pagination anyways. See https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Athena OFFSET support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298622/aws-athena-offset-support)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_name offset 0 rows LIMIT 100;
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_name offset 100 rows LIMIT 100;
```

Using this you can do pagination for 100 rows